# Is installing Kali on LiveDVD advisable?

Tags: livecd, kali-linux

I want to install the Kali penetration testing software on a DVD or a CD as a LiveDVD / LiveCD. Google turned up results on installation for a Usb and hard drive / disk installation, but nothing for LiveCD/DVD. One site said that LiveDVD installation isn't suggested for Kali, because of installation problems.

Will installing Kali on a DVD or CD give me anything serious to worry about? What about installing the image on a DVD / CD and booting from that (not sure of that's similar or different from LiveCD/DVD)? And if I do install it, what problems will it give me?

Comment: aren't the ISO at http://www.kali.org/downloads/ supposed to be used as live cd?

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that the official ISO you can download from the [website](http://www.kali.org/downloads/) are indeed Live-DVD iso (except for the minimal ones, which only allow installing).

If you aren't satisfied, the official [documentation](http://www.kali.org/official-documentation/) covers how to [build your own customized image](http://docs.kali.org/category/live-build)

By the way they also suggest beginner linux users [against using kali](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux), which is supposed to be targeted at professional penetration testers.